# Jersey: The request resource is not available

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to get my first Jersey web service project to work but I am getting this error `Jersey: The requested resource is not available.` I have installed `Jersey 2.16` by eclispe Maven and installed `Tomcat 8.0.21` I have craeted the MessageResource.java class inside `scr/main/java - org.test.messanger`

I am typing this link:

`http://localhost:8080/messanger/webapi/messages`

If I klick this link `http://localhost:8080/messanger/webapi/myresource` I am getting `Got it!`

I added Jersy with maven with this data:

- org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
- jersey-Quickstart-webapp
- 2.16

MessageResource.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessages(){
        return "Hello world";
    }

}
```

Working code:

```
package org.test.messanger;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.test.messanger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please stop deleting your posts, and posting the **exact** same question again. This is already the third time.

Comment: What you're showing us looks fine. The problem is with something you're not showing us or telling us. Just to let you know the reason you probably haven't been getting answers, is because the problem is not reproducible or discoverable from what you have provided. That's not to say you haven't provided a good example/well asked question, it's just what you have provided looks like a solid working example. I work with that archetype all the time and have never had the problem you are facing

Comment: I'd say just run a `mvn clean package`. Take the `.war` from the `target` and put it in the Tomcat `webapp`. Delete any old wars (exploded wars). Start Tomcat. Then look in the exploded war, inside the webapps, make sure the class is in the WEB-INF/classes

Comment: @peeskillet Ok. And what alse have I to post to figure it out? I am just trying to  work this tutorial through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbP1ZCDfIfw&index=15&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn for it  I have installed every thing fresh.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't know. The information you have provided looks good. Only thing I can think is that when you start Tomcat, the `.war` will explode into a directory with the same name as the `.war`. Look in that directory, and open `WEB-INF/classes/org/test/messanger` and make sure the `MessageResource.class` is in there.

Comment: Also if you look in the Tomcat logs, there might be some information about the problem. Maybe a stacktrace. if you find something, post it.  Any more detailed information about the problem would help.

Comment: @peeskillet the tomcat  is running but the logs directory is empty, where can I find the log file of tomcat? And what is `.war` and where to find is in the target?

Comment: From the command line go to the project root, and type `mvn clean package`. A `yourproject.war` file should be created in the "target" directory of your project. Copy that to the Tomcat `webapps` folder. Make sure all other `.war` files and directories with the same name are removed. Then start Tomcat manually `bin/startup(.sh/.bat)`. Then look for the class file as described above

Comment: I see that working code has package `package org.test.messanger;` but not working don't have package

Comment: @michaldo it has in the class otherwise I would have gotten an error.

Comment: @peeskillet: my project is in `Simple Jersey project` directory and I am there from the `cmd prompt`but when I typed `mvn  clean package` or `mvn clean org.test` it said the command is wrong?

Comment: How did you create the project? Was it from your IDE? If so just clean and  build the project from the context menu, and the `.war` file should be created an the "target" dir of the project.

Comment: I followed the guide of the guy in the tutorial which I want to work through  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skltzZH7i4w&index=11&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn I created it from eclipse maven but I will try to create once from the context menu. Thanks for your support.

Comment: It works now because I have  never restart the Tomcat server after creating the new class; why I have always to restart the server to get it to work. My Mistake was that I never restart the server after creating the new class? I thought it is like wamp with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.

1. Copy the messenger.jar from **target/messenger.jar** and paste it inside tomcat folder at location **TOMCAT_DIR/tomcat/webapps**. 
    **TOMCAT_DIR** is the directory location for tomcat in your local.
2. Now go to TOMCAT_DIR/tomcat/bin and start **startup.bat** or **startup.sh**.
3. Now open url http://localhost:8080/messanger/webapi/messages. This should work.

If it worked then go and delete the configured tomcat server from eclipse and configure it one more time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is working just fine, but the messenger.jar was distributed into your Tomcat server's build directory the first time you attempted to host this project.

If you are not properly managing Tomcat through the Manager portal

[localhost:port#/manager](http://localhost:8080/manager)

by undeploying the project then Tomcat will attempt to rebuild your older project.

Alternatively to using tomcat's Manager GUI, in your Tomcat directory **TOMCAT_DIR/tomcat/work** delete the folder with the same name as your project and when you revisit the URL Tomcat will build the latest deployment from your **TOMCAT_DIR/tomcat/webapps** folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The problem with me was that I didn't build my eclipse project and was directly trying to run it on the server.

- Right-click on your project
- Click on `Build Project`
- Once project is built, run it on the server.